# Get binding object from Tap event

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to access the object that I bound a `DataTemplate` to, specifically I only need one int value. I've linked the main Grid from within the DataTemplate to an event handler via Tap:

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="joinTemplate">
  <Grid Tag="{Binding index}" DataContext="{Binding}" Tap="select_Click" ...>
    ...
  </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

My handler looks like:

```
private void select_Click(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
```

The problem is that I still can't access `sender.DataContext` or `sender.Tag`. However, when I run it in the debugger and look at it through Watch, I can get to both the `DataContext` and Tag by simply expanding "base" twice. That should mean that the object that I'm being given inherits those objects and is somehow the child of the original Grid, however, I thought that the sender was always the `Grid` you bound the handler to? To get the actual element that I tapped I'd have to use, for this example, `e.OriginalSource`, right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just cast `sender` to the appropriate type to access the `DataContext` property:

```
((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext
```

Then, the same way, you'll have to bind the value to whichever type you binded to the grid. For instance, if you binded an object of type `Model`:

```
var model = (Model)((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm :)